# Execute Resolve-DnsName in a runspace within a job

Tags: powershell, jobs, runspace

The following code works fine:

```bsh
$ScriptBlock = {
    Resolve-DnsName -name BELCL003000
}

 $Pool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, 6)
    $Pool.ApartmentState = 'MTA'
    $Pool.Open()
    $Runspaces = @()

    $Runspace = [PowerShell]::Create()
    $null = $Runspace.AddScript($ScriptBlock)
    # $null = $Runspace.AddArgument($TestWaveGroupName)
    $Runspace.RunspacePool = $Pool
    $Runspaces += @{
        Pipe   = $Runspace
        Status = $Runspace.BeginInvoke()
    }

    while ($Runspaces.Status -ne $null) {
        $CompletedRunspaces = $Runspaces.Where( { $_.Status.IsCompleted -eq $true })
        foreach ($C in $CompletedRunspaces) {
            $C.Pipe.EndInvoke($C.Status)
            $C.Status = $null
        }
    }

    $Pool.Close()
    $Pool.Dispose()
```

However, when I wrap it all in a `job` there suddenly is no output anymore for the same hostname:

```bsh
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $Pool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, 6)
    $Pool.ApartmentState = 'MTA'
    $Pool.Open()
    $Runspaces = @()

    $Runspace = [PowerShell]::Create()
    $null = $Runspace.AddScript($ScriptBlock)
    # $null = $Runspace.AddArgument($TestWaveGroupName)
    $Runspace.RunspacePool = $Pool
    $Runspaces += @{
        Pipe   = $Runspace
        Status = $Runspace.BeginInvoke()
    }

    while ($Runspaces.Status -ne $null) {
        $CompletedRunspaces = $Runspaces.Where( { $_.Status.IsCompleted -eq $true })
        foreach ($C in $CompletedRunspaces) {
            $C.Pipe.EndInvoke($C.Status)
            $C.Status = $null
        }
    }

    $Pool.Close()
    $Pool.Dispose()
}

Get-Job | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Am I missing something obvious here? I've tried to add `Import-Module DnsClient` within the `ScriptBlock` but without success.

Other `ScriptBlocks` return output without a problem using this method, just not the `Resolve-DnsName` CmdLet. The job approach is used in a form to allow the form to stay responsive.